# Dual boot setup for two copies of Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, multi-boot

I have two hard drives (one for my business and one for personal). I have installed Windows 7 on each drive. However, I cannot get any sort of dual boot to work. It seems that Windows only recognizes that Windows 7 is installed, so when the boot loader comes up it just lets me choose the version of Windows 7 on that hard drive, without showing me the option to boot to the other drive. I know I can just choose the hard drive to boot to from the BIOS, which is kind of like a boot loader, but I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Is there any way to configure a boot loader (with a piece of software?) so that I do not need to select the hard drive I want to boot to from the BIOS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) will take care of this for you.

Once you install it:

1. Add an Entry
2. Hit Windows
3. Hit 7/Vista dropdown menu.
4. Perhaps set a custom name here so you can differentiate the two
5. Point it to your second installation.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, if you boot from the Windows 7 installation media and select repair, the Windows 7 on the other disk will be added to the BCD file. You can then select which Windows 7 you want to boot to at startup. There is no need to purchase additional software.

Boot from the installation media and click "Next", as shown below.

[image: 81]

Click on "Install now", as shown below.

[image: 82]

Wait while installer search for Windows installations, as shown below.

[image: 83]

Click on "Repair and restart". If you wish, you can first click on "View details".

[image: 84]

This is pop up presented, if "View details" is selected.

[image: 85]

After restarting you should get the Windows Boot Manager selection screen shown below.

[image: 86]

If you wish, the titles of the available selections can be modified, as well as, the length of the selection timer. The command to use is `bcdedit`.

Comment: Awesome alternative option!

Answer (score 0):

Set up additional W7 OS using easyBCD-free, and an external enclosure connected via eSata, with a HDD that came from a desktop that failed (looks like motherboard), on another desktop that was itself already running W7.
Both PCs had essentially the same hardware - which must have made driver compatibility much simpler, and it worked very well.
All I did was download easyBCD, install it and add the second W7 OS to the list of available 0Ss, following the instructions given in No. 7, above, and those given here: [Is possible to load Windows 7 from the eSATA drive, even if it's not supported in BIOS?](https://superuser.com/questions/431218/is-possible-to-load-windows-7-from-the-esata-drive-even-if-its-not-supported-i)
It ran at the first restart.  I think the only thing I adjusted was the delay given for the default option to kick in, which looked to long at 30 sec.
eSata connection is a must.  Tried quite a few times with USB without success - looks like it is incompatible to run an OS from an external enclosure usng USB.